# Linkedin Mobile SDK Android

Tags: android, authentication, sdk, linkedin-api

I was integrating Linkedin mobile sdk for android. On Connect with Linkedin it prompts user to download Linkedin app first.
Also in documentations https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth
list the following scenario
**Is the LinkedIn application installed on the device?**

Is there a work around to get a Login Dialog(Like Facebook Sdk) to make the user signin and return to the app

Comment: You have to install LinkedIn https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk application for working LI SDK well.and i haven't saw any snippet for login dialog much like facebook in LI Mobile SDK for android.

Comment: @AnoopM, the SDK provided in the link you gave has two file main and test, if i try to use it as a library, the required methods aren't getting imported.

Comment: @ManishSB Check grade for  compile project(':linkedin-sdk').

Comment: @AnoopM you can add it in gradle ;) https://github.com/Yazon2006/LinkedIn-auth-sample

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this in eclipse?